# 2 custom views within an activity

Tags: android, canvas, view, android-custom-view

Deal All

I have a game that is a customized view, canvas and onDraw etc. In the onSize changed it gets screen width and heightand there are animations etc. and is working well. Now what I wanted to do is to reduce the size of the whole view by 80% and then use the rest 20% (bottom) for displaying another view. Searched all over for almost half a day unfortunately couldn't find answer or couldn't understand the answers supplied.

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you use [LinearLayout](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/linear.html) in your android xml and define 2 custom views there? And you can also add [weights](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/linear.html#Weight) to those views so as to maintain the 80-20% ratio.

Comment: I tried this. The way my custom view is defined in main activity is - Myview myView = new Myview(this); setContentView(myView); when I am putting it in LinearLayout it is taking screen size from init (onsizechanged) and throwing error. I have no physical xml file by the way.

Comment: Am not sure what you are trying to do? When you do `setContentView(myView);` only your `myView` will be displayed in the entire screen, no matter what you do! (The other custom view wont be displayed) That's why you create an android xml (or you can set it dynamically also) and set it to a `LinearLayout` and then add your custom view to it.

Comment: I have a lot of bitmaps in the game that are scaled using the screen width and height that I get from onSizeChanged (int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh). So I am not getting how to tell the activity to give 80% of height to one view and 20% of height to another view.

Comment: That's exactly what LinearLayout's weights are for. By setting one's weight=".2" and the second's to ".8", you're effectively telling the system you want the Layout to take up 80% and 20% of the available width of the Layout, respectively (yes, I agree it seems counter-intuitive).

Comment: For some reason when I do that same in LinearLayout it is pointing error towards onSizeChanged in the CustomView code. Anybody please?

Comment: One additional info that might help. When I am adding another custom view to the LL which doesn't have code for onsizechanged, it shows no errors.

Comment: What error are you getting exactly? Runtime error? Is it a crash?

Answer (score 0):

create layout xml like this:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent">

<com.your.pacakage.YourView
    android:layout_weight="0.8"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"        
    />


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_weight="0.2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    />
```

Where "com.your.pacakage.YourView" is your game view package. 
Next add this layout to setContent.

```
setContent(R.layout.main)
```